# How to initialise a Case record from a Customer record in SuiteTalk?

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

Using SuiteTalk, how can I initialise a new Case record based on a Customer record?

To be clear, I want to emulate selecting Create New > Case on a Customer record in the NetSuite website:

[image]

Comment: Which programming language and IDE are you using?

Comment: I don't mind what language the answer uses. It can even be XML. I'm using C# in VS Pro 2013.